# WebService C# and HTML5

Tags: c#, web-services, html

I want to realize an interface using HTML5 and bind it to an exisisting C# application. I saw that to realize this application i have to use a WebService , but I don't know how make comunication between the c# application and the page in HTML5. My questions are:

1) How create the webservice in Visual Studio 2010 Express Edition, and where it must be saved

2) How allow the comunication between application, web service and interface

I have already installed and running IIS.

Comment: Have you at least googled a bit?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just make Restful services, whether in WCF or Asp.net MVC
2. Call those services using Ajax from jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to create the service and Access it with Ajax/jquery.
This Page will explain you step for step http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37727/Prepare-a-JSON-Web-Service-and-access-it-with-JQue